# How to execute process in Python where data is written to stdin?

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, stdin, io-redirection

I have a flag in my Python script which specifies whether I setup and use an external process or not. This process is a command called `my_command` and it takes data from standard input. If I was to run this on the command-line, it would be something like:

```
$ my_command < data > result
```

I want to use a Python script to generate lines of `data` by modifying standard input and feeding it to `my_command`.

I'm doing something like this:

```
import getopt, sys, os, stat, subprocess

# for argument's sake, let's say this is set to True for now
# in real life, I use getopt.getopt() to decide whether this is True or False
useProcess = True

if useProcess:
    process = subprocess.Popen(['my_command'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

for line in sys.stdin:
    # parse line from standard input and modify it
    # we store the result in a variable called modified_line
    modified_line = line + "foo"

    # if we want to feed modified_line to my_command, do the following:
    if useProcess:
        process.stdin.write(modified_line)

    # otherwise, we just print the modified line
    else:
        print modified_line
```

However, `my_command` behaves as if it does not receive any data and quits with an error state. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Let's say my Python script is called `my_Python_script`. Let's say I would normally pass `my_command` a file called `data` over standard input:

```
$ my_command < data > result
```

But now I'm passing it to `my_Python_script` instead:

```
$ my_Python_script < data > some_other_result
```

I want `my_Python_script` to conditionally set up a subprocess that runs `my_command` on the contents of `data` (which are modified by `my_Python_script` before being passed to `my_command`). Does this make more sense?

If I was using `bash` as a scripting language, I would conditionally decide to run one of two functions. One would pipe lines of data to `my_command`. The other would not. Can this be done with Python?

Comment: What kind of file is `my_command`? Is it a shell script? Python script? You might want to try something like *['/bin/bash', 'my_command']* or something similar for Python script.

Comment: you could write `my_python_script` as a Unix filter instead. Then the python script knows nothing about `my_command` and just reads from stdin, modifies it somehow, and prints to stdout: `<data my_python_script | my_command >some_other_result

Comment: If `stdout=PIPE` then you should read from it otherwise the process might block if it generates enough output.

Comment: A simple example of two-way communication between a primary process and a subprocess can be found here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52841475/1349673

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After writing to the stdin, you need to close it:

```
    process.stdin.write(modified_line)
    process.stdin.close()
```

#### Update

I failed to notice that the `process.stdin.write()` was executed in a for loop. In which case, you should move the `process.stdin.close()` to outside the loop.

Also, Raymond mentioned that we should call `process.wait()` as well. So the updated code should be:

```
for ...
    process.stdin.write(modified_line)

process.stdin.close()
process.wait()
```

Comment: This throws a `ValueError` exception on the second pass through the `for` loop: `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`. The command `my_command` processes multiple lines (in reality, it mimics a specific application of UNIX `sort`) so the stdin handle needs to stay open, I'd think.

Comment: Can you close after the for loop? My bad.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to `process.stdin.close()` as mentioned by @HaiVu, did you do `process.wait()` to wait for the command to finish before getting the result?

Comment: I forgot about `process.wait()`. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you may be confusing arguments and stdin. Your command should be

```
$ <data> | mycommand result
```

with data being passed in once the command is called.

Taking an input is done with the `raw_input` builtin function. (http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html)

Comment: I don't understand. I'm trying to pass `my_command` modified data from within the script, not have the end user type in data manually  via the terminal. Everything should be processed within the script. Does this make more sense?

Comment: @AlexReynolds if you were typing in at the shell. How would you pass in multiple lines of input as an argument to a command? I think you are confusing arguments(ie: `command arg1 arg2 arg2`) and stdin(ie: `(echo arg1; echo arg2; echo arg3) | command`. You have to explain which one you want

Comment: I think the confusion is that if you are calling `$ python name_of_script.py <filename> result` you are not passing the file standard input, you are passing the file as an argument. You can get a list of arguments from `sys.argv`.

Comment: If I use `$ my_Python_script < data > result` without all the `subprocess` stuff, it handles standard input and output just fine, so I don't think file arguments are the issue here. In fact, if I leave out the redirect, then the `for` loop hangs, waiting for standard input. I'm just trying to figure out how to incorporate a process instance of `subprocess` into this script.

Comment: @AlexReynolds, does this command equivalent to the one you provided? `cat data | my_Python_script > result`. Just to clean up confusion.