# passing pandas dataframe into a python subprocess.Popen as an argument

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subprocess

I am attempting to call a python script from a master script. I need the dataframe to be generated only one from within the master script and then passed on to the subprocess script as an argument to be used inside the subprocess.

Following is my attempt at writing the required python master script.

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
import pandas as pd

test_dataframe = pd.read_excel(r'C:\test_location\file.xlsx',sheetname='Table')

sp = Popen(["python.exe",'C:/capture/test.py'], shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
sp.communicate(test_dataframe)
```

And here is the error: 
`TypeError: argument 1 must be convertible to a buffer, not DataFrame`

This is my first time trying to use the subprocess module so i am not very good at it yet. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a complete example for Python 3.6 of two-way communication between the master script and a subprocess.

**master.py**

```
import pandas as pd
import pickle
import subprocess

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\test_location\file.xlsx',sheetname='Table')

result = subprocess.run(['python', 'call_model.py'], input=pickle.dumps(df), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
returned_df = pickle.loads(result.stdout)
assert df == returned_df
```

If there is a problem, you can check `result.stderr`.

**subroutine.py**

```
import pickle
import sys

data = pickle.loads(sys.stdin.buffer.read())
sys.stdout.buffer.write(pickle.dumps(data))
```

Answer (score 3):

Subprocess launches another application. The ways that processes may communicate between each other significantly differ from ways that functions communicate within python program. You need to pass your DataFrame through a non pythonic environment. So you need to serialize it in-to a text and then deserialize it on other end. For example you can use pickle module and then `sp.communicate(pickle.dumps(test_dataframe))` on one end end `pickle.loads(sys.stdin.read())` on another. Or you can write your DataFrame as csv and then parse it again. Or you can use any other format.

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for the reply. I attempted to use pickle but after going through the master script, it closes itself without giving any error and no command from subprocess script is run at all.

Comment: Are you sure, that subproess is not executed? May be it is executed, but you do not check if it has finished successfully? Also check output from the process, it is returned by ```sp.comminucate```. Beside that, check what ```shell=True``` does. You are passing command as an array, but also specify ```shell=True```.

Comment: My subprocess begins with a print command and ends with raw_input() for me to see whether it runs or not, the pop up window doesn't show anything before closing by itself. I tried with and without using shell, i dont get anything from subprocess either way. I tried running without stdin, stdout and stderr, only then the first print command from subprocess runs but hangs at pickle.loads(sys.stdin.read()) forever.